# Using list elements as function calls ?

Tags: function-construction, syntax, argument-patterns

Is it possible to take elements of a matrix or list and use them as arguments of a function? I have a matrix of values, something like this;

```
  listed = {{3, 2, 1 , 5, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 7, 5,  2, 1, 1}};
```

Now, if we take a function like *Cylinder* it requires something of the form;

```
 Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}},t]]
```

with 7 arguments to specify it. What I'd like to do is take the rows of the columns and call these in, and do this for every row in the most automated fashion possible.In the example matrix I'd like Mathematica to render something like the image below -

[image]

This should be simple, but I'm running into problems. I've tried using forms of MapIndexed and Apply, but have had no joy and am open to suggestion on the best approach, as eventually I'll have to apply this so much bigger data sets than 7 x 3 !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{#1, #2, #3}, {#4, #5, #6}}, #7] & @@@ listed]
```

Or

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[ArrayReshape[{##}, {2, 3}], #7] & @@@ listed]
```

Or

```
MapThread[Cylinder[ArrayReshape[{##}, {2, 3}], #7] &, Transpose@listed] // Graphics3D
```

Or

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[ArrayReshape[#, {2, 3}], #[[-1]]] & /@ listed]
```

Comment: The last one is best if `listed` is packed as `Map` will only unpack the top level.

Comment: These are brilliant - thanks so much! I need to learn the nature of the @@@ handles a little better...

Answer (score 4):

```
listed = {{3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 7, 5, 
    2, 1, 1}};

Graphics3D[Cylinder[{#[[1 ;; 3]], #[[4 ;; 6]]}, #[[7]]] & /@ listed]
```

[image]